# Why can't I delete javascript values declared with var?

Tags: javascript

example:

```
x = "Hello";
delete x; // returns true, x is removed

var y = "Hello";
delete y; // returns false, y is not removed
```

I'm not interested in *How* this happens, I want to know *why* the language has this feature.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strictly speaking the first `x` is not a variable but a property of the global object. In browsers it's usually `window` (so `x = "Hello"` is equal to `window.x = "Hello"`). You can't use `delete` to remove variables but you can use it to remove object properties, and that's what it does in the first case.

Comment: So can I then see it as, like, removing Properties from objects is like removing Elements from Arrays?

Comment: Definitely. `delete` removes a property from an object. The `var` keyword attaches your variable to the current local context, while declaring without `var` implicitly attaches the variable to a global object, i.e `window`. However, when `var` attaches to `window` (root context), `delete` still won't work.

Answer (score 5):

[This page](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/) has a lengthy explanation that spells out the why.

The short answer is delete is for properties, not variables.  var y creates a variable.  x = "something" creates a property of the global scope.

Also note that not all browsers handle delete the same.  *cough cough IE*

Comment: Nice link :) Just curious, how'd you come across it?